# Tried to register two views with the same name ProgressBarAndroid

Tags: javascript, react-native

Using react version 16.0.0 with react-native version 0.49.1 raises the red screen error "Tried to register two views with the same name ProgressBarAndroid". Removing all imports and instances of ProgressBarAndroid results in a well functioning program. Downgrading to react-native version 0.48.4 works as well. How do I use ProgressBarAndroid with the latest React Native version?

Comment: could you share a piece of your code?

Comment: Me too at:   
"react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
"react-native": "0.49.3",

Comment: I should make a new project with the minimal code to recreate the issue. I frankly just haven't. Been prioritizing other aspects of the web/server/native project, but it's literally just importing ProgressBarAndroid that raises the issue.

Comment: @mattferrin accept the below answer if it's the correct solution

Comment: @ACVM Accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

React Native starting from version 0.49 triggers this error if you are trying to call `requireNativeComponent()` for same component more than once. Even if they are called from different modules.

I had similar issue with custom view `MyCustomView`. So I just wrapped it in a single module:

```
// MyCustomView.js
import {requireNativeComponent} from 'react-native'
const MyCustomView = requireNativeComponent('MyCustomView', null)
export default MyCustomView
```

Though it might not be your exact case the root cause is the same.

Comment: @teivaz Can you provide how can we find where it is use multiple times???

Comment: @teivaz I am still getting this issue when I tried integrating following library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-linechart.  Any solution

Comment: It can also happen during hot reloads of the file that calls `requireNativeComponent`, even if `requireNativeComponent` is only called for this name once (error disappears on full reload of the app or re-running the build). This proposed solution (moving `requireNativeComponent` calls to a very small component-specific file that rarely changes) is a good fix for that development nuisance too 

Comment: @BhaveshJariwala If your own code calls `requireNativeComponent`, just do a find-in-all-files on `requireNativeComponent('YourViewName')`. If the error comes from a library you installed, maybe they goofed and called it twice, but far more likely you've installed different versions of the same library (e.g. you have a dep on `"react-native-wotsit": "^1.2.3"` and some other library demands  `"react-native-wotsit": "^3.2.1"` so your build contains 1.x and 3.x and each copy calls `requireNativeComponent`). Try `yarn why` or `npm ls`. Or you just see the error in hot reloads (see my other comment)

Comment: @user56reinstatemonica8: Thanks for providing response.

Answer (score 2):

```js
import ReactNative  from 'react-native';

const description = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor( ReactNative, 'requireNativeComponent' )

if ( !description.writable ) {
  Object.defineProperty( ReactNative, 'requireNativeComponent', {
    value: (function () {
      const cache = {}
      const _requireNativeComponent = ReactNative.requireNativeComponent

      return function requireNativeComponent( nativeComponent ) {

        if ( !cache[ nativeComponent ] ) {
          cache[ nativeComponent ] = _requireNativeComponent( nativeComponent )
        }

        return cache[ nativeComponent ]
      }
    })(), writable: true
  } )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this during hot-reload in development. What causes the issue is the following: however JS is reloaded, the native code is still holding onto the same reference that it previously held onto. Whenever JS runs `requireNativeComponent` with the same `viewName`, it throws because the previous reference for the given `viewName` still exists. [Here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/ReactNative/requireNativeComponent.js) is the source file of `requireNativeComponent`, which clearly states that it should be memozied on the React Native side and only initialized once. Thus, the answer of @Teivaz is satisfying and no further hacking (like the answer of @蒋宏伟) is needed. If your code is structured well, you don't have to use any manual caching because your import structure solves it for you. :)