# React-Native: Use react-native-linear-gradient with lottie

Tags: react-native, lottie

I am using `Lottie` and lottie uses `react-native-linear-gradient` as a dependancy.
Now the problem is that I need to use `react-native-linear-gradient`, If I use it via npm install (as another package). I get the error, 
`tried to register two view with same BVLinearGradient` Is there any way through which I can use The linear gradient as well as lottie? or maybe i could use `react-natve-linear-gradient` through lottie somehow?

Comment: I had both on my project, but I installed linear-gradient then Lottie and found no issue

Comment: Sorry...it didn't work as expected my bad....i still upvoted you
Thank you

Comment: can you check on your java files to see if you don't request linear twice?

Comment: might be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46613149/tried-to-register-two-views-with-the-same-name-progressbarandroid

Comment: i am debugging in ios

Comment: take a look at this issue https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient/issues/230

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had both on my project, but I installed linear-gradient then Lottie and found no issue.

You can try it.

this is my MainApplication

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
        new LottiePackage(),
        new LinearGradientPackage(),
        new PickerViewPackage(),
        new SnackbarPackage(),
        new Sha256Package(),
        new FIRMessagingPackage(),
        new ReactNativeContacts(),
        new RNSpinkitPackage(),
        new ReactNativeLocalizationPackage(),
        new BlurViewPackage(),
        new VectorIconsPackage(),
        new ReactNativeConfigPackage(),
        new RCTCameraPackage(),
        new TlvInterpreterPackage(),
        new TlvGeneratorPackage()
  );
}
```